# Is it possible to hide events in a Calendly embed?

Tags: javascript, html, embed, calendly

I want to create embeds to my Calendly landing page that only display certain event types. The code that Calendly provides me to embed my landing page is

```html
<!-- Calendly inline widget begin -->
<div class="calendly-inline-widget" data-url="https://calendly.com/[My Calendly link]" style="min-width:320px;height:900px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js" async></script>
<!-- Calendly inline widget end -->
```

which generates an embed that looks like this[image: Calendly Embed Page]
and displays the six event types I have created. These event types are really 3 events with English and Spanish duplicates. I would like to be able to create an embed that looks like this one but only displays the English events, and a second one that only displays the Spanish events.

Other solutions I have considered, but which would be less preferable than this, are:

- Creating two Calendly accounts, one to host the Spanish landing page and one to host the English landing page. This is less preferable because it would require coordinating the availability of my calendar between the two accounts.
- Embedding the event types individually and putting all the Spanish ones in one place and all the English ones in another. This is less preferable because I prefer the appearance and behavior of the landing page embed over that of three individual event embeds on one page.
- Creating a single version of the each event and translating the embed when necessary using code on my own website. This is less preferable because it seems particularly difficult to do and must either rely on automated translation, which is faulty, or manually written translation, which may need to be updated any time Calendly updates wording or designs in their embed.

I read through Calendly's documentation of their embed feature, including https://help.calendly.com/hc/en-us/articles/223147027. I tried adding `?hide_event_type_details=1` to the url in the embed as they suggest, but I now understand that this hides details on the events rather than enabling the hiding of any particular event. I also tried embedding events individually as detailed above, but aspects of the form and function of a landing page embed are preferable.